# Copy records from two database in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite

How can I copy records from two Database, "db1.db" and "db2.db" with different column structure?

Comment: To what destination are you copying the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will have to be done a table at a time, not a database at the time.

Since you mention the schema is different between source and destination, you will have to normalize this before making a copy.  Most automated tools you might use will probably require the same schema to automate this process, or require you to map source columns to destination columns.